# Is plugging directly into a router w/ CAT5 faster than a wall port

Tags: ethernet, network

If I have a cat 5 cable plugged into my router would it be faster than the ethernet port available on my wall? During the previous testing I did, I had a 20+ Mbs/s download difference while plugged into my router compared to my wall. Could this just be a coincidence?

Comment: What absolute rates are you talking about? A 21-down-to-20 Mbit/s makes a whole lot more difference than 1000-down-to-980 Mbit/s. Additionally, gauging your local network speed with an external source is a very rough art.

Comment: above should read "21-down-to-_1_ Mbit/s"...

Comment: You need to edit your question to include more information. How is the network connected? For example, where does the wall cable connect? What are the network devices models and configurations. Please include any relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a lot of reasons:

- The cable going through you wall is faulty.
- The cable or the connectors are not standard complaint for the desired speed.
- The connector patching was incorrect (on the cable or on the wall socket).
- The path of the cable inside the wall isn't standard complaint.
- The total length of cabling is more than 100m (328 feet).

CAT5 cabling is able to manage speeds up to 100 Mbps if everything was installed according to the standards.

Comment: Cat5 has been obsolete for 15+ years. Cat5e can handle up to 2.5 Gbit/s for 100m.

Answer (score 0):

Cat5e is rated for 1000Mb/s up to the standard 100 meters. CAT5e  speeds up to 1Gb/s, or CAT6a for speeds up to 10Gb/s. CAT5e is plenty for todays household, but if you are trying to future proof you may consider CAT6a. Some people wire in the walls with CAT6a but use CAT5e patch cords to the devices since they don't currently run anything over 1Gb/s.